# Marklogic query based on values of multiple attributes of the same element

Tags: marklogic

I have the following xmls:

sample1.xml
    
    `<root>
      <subjectInfo>
        <subject id="001"/>
        <subject id="002" role="cross"/>
      </subjectInfo>
    </root>`

sample2.xml
    
    `<root>
      <subjectInfo>
        <subject id="002"/>
        <subject id="001" role="cross"/>
      </subjectInfo>
    </root>`

I am searching for the documents where value of `id` attribute of `subject` is "001" but `role`(if it's there) of the same `subject` element is not "cross".So, In my example the result should contain `sample1.xml` and not `sample2.xml`

I thought the following query would do the job:

```
<code>
cts:search(/root,
        cts:near-query((
           cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"),xs:QName("id"),"001"),
           cts:not-query(cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"),xs:QName("role"),"cross"))),0)

           )
</code>
```

But it does not(returns an empty sequence). Please give me one that does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @wst said, the `cts:not-query` matches both documents. `cts:*` queries match document fragments, not subtrees. You can match the opposite of your conditions, by nesting the `cts:element-attribute-value-query` constructors inside of a `cts:element-query`. This will match `sample2.xml`:

```
cts:search(/root,
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("subject"),
    cts:and-query((
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"),xs:QName("id"),"001"),
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"),xs:QName("role"),"cross")))))
```

Perhaps you can adjust your query requirements so this is sufficient. If not, you can exclude the documents that match this search, using the `except` operator. This will match `sample1.xml`:

```
cts:search(/root,
  cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"),xs:QName("id"),"001"))

except

cts:search(/root,
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("subject"),
    cts:and-query((
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"),xs:QName("id"),"001"),
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"),xs:QName("role"),"cross")))))
```

If your documents have unique identifiers, you could add range indices and use one of the `cts:*-values` functions to get the unique IDs for documents matching the second `cts:search`, and then use `cts:not-query` and `cts:*-range-query` to exclude the documents from the first `cts:search`.

Comment: Thank you very much.That explains quite a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that the `cts:not-query` is matching on both documents, and therefore excludes them from the result set.

This may not be sufficient, since it's not an index-only query, but you could supplement the `cts:search` results by filtering out false positives:

```
cts:search(/root,
  cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("subject"), 
    xs:QName("id"), "001"))[subjectInfo/subject[@id='001' and not(@role='cross')]
```